# How can I change the property of a nested object like so?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

```
const album3 = {
  title: 'Fear of Music',
  albumDetails: {
    released: 'August 3, 1979',
    label: 'Sire',
    formats: ['Cassette']
  }
};
```

question: Update the released property of album3 from a string into a Date object using that string.

I have tried many variations of something like this:

```
album3.albumDetails.Date = album3.albumDetails.released
```

Comment: It sounds like it wants you to convert the string to `Date` object. For example: `album3.albumDetails.released = new Date(album3.albumDetails.released);`

Comment: That worked, thank you! I knew I was close but didn't quite understand what it wanted. I appreciate it!